# Knockout: Dynamically creating observables based on an array of unknown length

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here's the situation:

I have a list of items which will be dynamically filled. The number of items in that list is unknown, and can vary from zero to hundreds of items.

When the page loads, this list should be loaded, and for every item, a checkbox (with label) should be generated. No problem there. Such a *list item* would look like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        Item 1
    </label>
</div>
```

Here comes the tricky part:

For each of these items, a `ko.observable()` should be created, so I can keep track of the `checked` binding of the checkboxes.

An ideal situation would be something like this (I know this won't work, just to illustrate my goal):

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var listItem$ = ko.observable(); // $ = i
}
```

So later on, I would be able to do something along the line of:

```
if (listItem4()) {
    //listItem is checked (=true), do some actions
}
```

I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: I think you want to check [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) and [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Comment: As that would suffice for the creation of the list with checkboxes, it would not for the creation of the observables for these checkboxes. Right?

Comment: It depends how you get your data. You might be interested in the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) too.

Comment: Data will probably be loaded like this: `$.getJSON(URL, self.listItems).done(function () {...});`, so the list will be filled with the names of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate each property to make it observable better way is to use knockout.mapping.js  pluggin.
So code will be like:-

```
self.itemList = ko.mapping.fromJS(list); //list that will come from server(ajax request)
```

Then just use checked binding to keep track selected checkboxes.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u855a/)

Comment: I originally didn't want any more .js files added to the project, but this seems inevitable. Thanks for this!

Comment: Is there a way to display this without the brackets? And is it possible to replace "[]" (when none is selected) with a string

Comment: yes you can use foreach on selected array. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u855a/2/